# Check for reboot pending status in VB

Tags: vb.net, registry

I'm currently trying to determine if a computer is in a "pending reboot" status after applying Microsoft patches in a VB program I'm writing.
I have the following:

```
Private Sub DoesKeyExist()
    Dim regKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
    regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\WindowsUpdate\\Auto Update\\RebootRequired", True)
    If regKey Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("No reboot pending.")
    Else
        MsgBox("Reboot is pending")
    End If
End Sub
```

This isn't working, however, and just returns Nothing each time. Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By using the .LocalMachine. part you are already searching in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. Try to use

```
regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\WindowsUpdate\\Auto Update\\RebootRequired", True)
```

instead.

Comment: I actually discovered that as soon as I submitted and changed it, however, it's still doing the same thing.

Comment: Found the solution!

Private Sub DoesKeyExist()

        Dim regKey As Object
        regKey = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.GetValue("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\WindowsUpdate\\Auto Update", "RebootRequired", Nothing)
        If regKey Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox("No reboot pending.")
        Else
            MsgBox("Reboot is pending")
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: Yes. And I actually spoke too soon. Apparently it's just passing "RebootRequired" as the value and not actually checking.